# how to implelement custom mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb

I using mongodb in my poject and interesting how to implement simple mongodb driver which will allow to run mongodb command like in a shell form. Just writing command in javascript and pushing it to mongodb, then geting result and deserializing it.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute your connection string in the code below.

While it would be extremely dangerous to provide this generally speaking (as it allows any command to execute), just call the `eval` function on the instance of the database that's returned.

This code is use the JavaScript/NodeJS driver:

```
var
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/default?w=1",
    function (err, db) {
        db.eval("db.version()", null, {noLock: true}, function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);                       
    });
});
```